# Advantages and Disadvantages of Using ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
Almost everyday of my life, im working with ROS, but sometimes i was thinking what is actually the advantages and disadvantages  using ROS.
Can anybody give me some explanation and theory about this? It is fine if u want explain it on education area, industry area or any area. thank you

regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200423/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-ros/) by [ghost](https://answers.ros.org/users/21020/ghost/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-01-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2015-01-06**:
Advantages and/or disadvantages...relative to *what*? Many papers have been written comparing robot software ([search](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=robot+software+comparison)) -- reading just a few would be tremendously educational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the following pages do great at explaining the advantages so I'll just provide links:

http://www.ros.org/is-ros-for-me/

http://www.ros.org/core-components/

http://www.ros.org/integration/

As for disadvantages, many of them are being addressed in ROS 2.0, you can read more about that [here](http://design.ros2.org/) (specifically [this](http://design.ros2.org/articles/why_ros2.html) article).

Personally, I'd add that it not being cross-platform is a disadvantage. While there are ways to use it with [Windows](http://wiki.ros.org/win_ros), [OSX](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source), and even [Andriod](http://wiki.ros.org/android), those operating systems are not currently fully supported.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2015-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Obviously, ROS shows a lot of advantages. However, basing on my experience so far, it is still not easy for new people to start. Another problem, we will spend more time to install the package (due to ROS versions, different computer configurations ...) and make it work, other than understanding the calculations of algorithm ^^.

---

Originally posted by [tn0432](https://answers.ros.org/users/21276/tn0432/) with karma: 60 on 2015-01-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) on 2015-01-07**:
I fully agree with that.
It takes long time to start, but once you got it, you will see it's advantages.